# How to add folder to SystemJS Config map?

Tags: angular, typescript, systemjs

I'm trying angular 2 with TS and SystemJS.
I would like to map one of my folders in `system.config.js`.

```
|_ app
|   |_ standalone
|   |  |_ rest.service.js
|   |  |_ rest.service.js.map
|   |  |_ rest.service.ts
|   |_ app.module.ts
|_ node_modules
|_ system.config.js
```

This is a simplified version of what I have in `system.config.js`:

```
System.config({
        paths: {
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        map: {           
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'stalone': 'app/standalone'
        },
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            stalone: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

Two of my imports in app.module.ts are:

```
import { RestService } from "stalone/rest.service";
import { NgModule }    from "@angular/core";
```

"@angular.core" does get imported without problems, but when importing "stalone/rest.service", I get the error:

```
Cannot find module 'stalone/rest.service'.
```

*I've only included files, that I think are relevant in this matter. If I've missed any, please let me know.*

Comment: I'm having the same problem, no luck yet. I'll let you know if I find anything useful!

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Comment: I'm not sure how the mapping would help as you are under app you can import into app.module.ts with `import { RestService } from "./standalone/rest.service"`. SystemJS will be expecting a module.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is not using `system.js` during compilation. If I understand correctly, you get this error during compilation, so that really means that `TypeScript` cannot find your module, not `system.js` that will do that in runtime.

It really works with angular because typescript is looking for files under all `node_modules` folders where it finds it, but this does not work for you, since your module is not under `node_modules`.

That's why you need to tell the ts compiler where to find your modules, something like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "stalone/*": ["app/standalone/*"]
    }
}
```

To understand how all this works in more details, you should really check the module resolution documentation for typescript [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping).

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error during typescript compilation, then add:

```
"compilerOptions": {
   ...
    "paths": {
        "standalone/*": [ "app/standalone/*" ]
    }
}
```

to your tsconfig.json

Note: you need TypeScript version 2.0 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this `'stalone': './app/standalone'`